# Elasticsearch MapperParsingException

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to index following data to elasticsearch,

```
{
"_id": "5619578c1983757a72efef15",
"aseg": {},
"cs": {
    "source": "None",
    "ss": "In Transit",
    "sr": "Weight Captured",
    "act": "+B",
    "pid": "BAG21678106",
    "st": "UD",
    "dest": "Bharatpur_DC (Rajasthan)",
    "u": "J",
    "sl": "Jaipur_Hub (Rajasthan)",
    "ud": "2015-10-12T14:59:44.270000",
    "sd": "2015-10-12T14:59:44.270000"
},

"nsl": [
    {
        "dt": [
            2015,
            10,
            10
        ],
        "code": "X-PPONM"
    },
    {
        "dt": [
            2015,
            10,
            11
        ],
        "code": "X-UCI"
    },
]
}
```

but in return i am getting this error

```
MapperParsingException[failed to parse [cs.nsl]]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[unknown property [dt]];
```

I checked the mapping, mapping is correct, nsl nested inside cs dict has a different mapping than nsl at root level.

```
            "cs": {
            "properties": {
                "act": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "add": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "asr": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "bucket": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "dest": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "dwbn": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "lcld": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "lat": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "lon": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "loc": {
                    "type": "double"
                },
                "nsl": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "ntd": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "pbs": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "pid": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "pupid": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "sd": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "sl": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "source": {
                    "properties": {
                        "source": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "source_id": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "source_type": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sr": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "ss": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "st": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "u": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "ud": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "vh": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
```

and for nsl at root level mapping is as follow

```
        "nsl": {
            "properties" : {
                "code" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                "dt" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        },
```

this is happening for only a few records, rest all are syncing fine.
there isn't any changes in payload.
Futher nsl is a sparse key inside cs.

Answer (score 2):

In your mapping nsl is as follows -

```
            "nsl": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
```

As per mapping , Elasticsearch is expecting a concrete string value to the nsl field but its a object array in the document you have provided. 
Elasticsearch once it has a mapping , its definite. You cant insert an object data into a string field.

Comment: so there are two keys for nsl, one is in the mail doc for which mapping is as described in last, and one nsl key is nested inside cs. which has a different mapping as shown above.

Comment: Yes , that is the issue. ES will assume the mapping of whichever document it sees first and rejects the other document.

Comment: OK that can be a case, therefore i tried passing a default value to doc (cs[nsl] = 'XXX' ) but still didn't work. futher i guess mapping of nsl at rool level should not conflict with mapping of nsl nested in side cs.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your document without pre-setting any mapping as follows:

```
{
    "aseg": {},
    "cs": {
        "source": "None",
        "ss": "In Transit",
        "sr": "Weight Captured",
        "act": "+B",
        "pid": "BAG21678106",
        "st": "UD",
        "dest": "Bharatpur_DC (Rajasthan)",
        "u": "J",
        "nsl":"foo",
        "sl": "Jaipur_Hub (Rajasthan)",
        "ud": "2015-10-12T14:59:44.270000",
        "sd": "2015-10-12T14:59:44.270000"
    },
    "nsl": [
        {
            "dt": [
                2015,
                10,
                10
            ],
            "code": "X-PPONM"
        },
        {
            "dt": [
                2015,
                10,
                11
            ],
            "code": "X-UCI"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the ES created the mapping as follows:

```
"nsl": {
    "properties": {
        "dt": {
            "type": "long"
        },
        "code": {
            "type": "string"
        }
     }
 }
```

As you can see ES put the "dt" type as "long" which is the internal representation of a date type. So, may be need to change that type?

Also, without seeing the successful document it is difficult to guess but I believe those documents do not have the "dt" field value.

Of course, you are free to put "not_analyzed" as you see fit for any field.